# Trouble with SQL CE and Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to get my program to use a LocalDataCache. I'm using Linq.

```
if (tempVehicle.VehicleFinancialInfo[0].askingPrice != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

askingPrice is a (decimal?) because VehicleFinancialInfo is a linq entityset.

The above if test works on SQL Express but it crashes the app in SQL Compact Edition. It gives the error "Specified Cast is not valid". Does anyone know what's going on. I need the program to work with both express and compact edition. Be gentle, I'm a noob to SQL and Linq

Comment: are you sure this is exactly where you're getting the exceptions?

Comment: I think so, Here is a snippit of the stacktrace from the error.

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data.SqlServerCe
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.GetDateTime(Int32 ordinal)
       at Read_VehicleFinancialInfo(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.Load()
       at System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at Vis2.FrmVehicleData..ctor(Vehicle _car, FrmMain Main)

Comment: it looks like something is trying to be converted to DateTime() Make sure your SQL Tables are exactly the same in SQL Express and SQL Compact. You might be missing a column or have columns in a different order.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll look it over when I get home from work. The local database was generated with the localdatabase cache wizard. I'd hope that it copied the express database correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Oops.. When the LocalDataCache wizard created the .sdf database, it created the datetime columns as nchar... Thanks Stan R.